# Injectivity of an integral transform

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, integration

For a bounded function $F: \mathbb R_{\ge 0} \to \mathbb R$ (*not necessarily non-negative*),  is it true that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^ks}{(s^2+x^2)^{(k+3)/2}} F(x) dx = 0 \text{ for all $s >0$} \iff F \equiv 0$$
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is a positive constant? Of course, one implication ($\leftarrow$) is true. What about the other one?

Comment: It's *not* true for the kernel $e^{-x}$, just arrange for cancellation of positive and negative parts (to refer to the Laplace transform, you'd have to consider $e^{-tx}$ for all $t>0$). The answer to your original question is *no* for the same reason. It might be more interesting if you assume that the integral is zero for all $k$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks for the remark! I changed the statement adding a parameter $s>0$. Does this suffice to prove the result?

Comment: It's still not working: if $k=1$, then $s$ isn't doing anything.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Sorry, this was just a typo: the exponent was supposed to be $(k +3)/2$

Comment: @Jun This remind me of Salem criterium for the Riemann hypothesis in: Salem, R., Sur une proposition equivalente à l'hypothèse de Riemann, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris vol 236 (1953) pp. 1127--1128.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think that $|x| F(|x|)$ ($x \in \mathbb R^{k+2}$) is the boundary value of a harmonic function $u$ in the half-space $\mathbb R^{k+2} \times (0, \infty)$, given by an appropriate [Poisson integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_upper_half-space):
$$ u(x,s) = c_k \int_{\mathbb R^{k+2}} |y| F(|y|) \, \frac{s}{(|x - y|^2 + s^2)^{(k+3)/2}} \, dy $$
with $c_k$ the normalisation constant. Then
$$ \begin{aligned} u(0,s) & = c_k \int_{\mathbb R^{k+2}} |y| F(|y|) \, \frac{s}{(|y|^2 + s^2)^{(k+3)/2}} \, dy \\ & = c_k' \int_0^\infty r^k F(r) \, \frac{s}{(r^2 + s^2)^{(k+3)/2}} dr . \end{aligned} $$
Thus, your equation says that $u(0,s) = 0$ for every $s > 0$.

Note that $u(x, s)$ is a radial function of $x$ for every $s > 0$. Since $u$ is also real-analytic, its power series expansion at $(0, s)$ with respect to $x$ is of the form
$$ u(x, s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(s) |x|^{2n} ,$$
and it can be differentiated under the sum. Since $\Delta_{x,s} u = 0$, we have
$$ 0 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(s) 2 n (2 n + k) |x|^{2n - 2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n''(s) |x|^{2n} ,$$
which shows that $a_n(s) = 0$ for every $n$. It follows that $u$ is identically zero, and therefore $F(x) = 0$ for almost all $x$.

---

Other proofs also seem feasible. For example:

- The equation says that the Mellin convolution of $F$ and another kernel, $x^k / (1 + x^2)^{(k+3)/2}$, is identically zero. Furthermore, the Mellin transform of the kernel $x^k / (1 + x^2)^{(k+3)/2}$ is everywhere non-zero (because by a substitution $x^2 = (1-t) / t$, it reduces to a beta integral). This means that the Mellin transform of $F$ (in the sense of distributions if $F$ is not nicely integrable) is necessarily equal to zero, and consequently $F$ is almost everywhere zero.
- After a substitution $x^2 = t$, the equation tells us that the generalised Cauchy–Stieltjes transform of $t^{k/2-1/2} F(t^{1/2})$ is zero along the half-line $(-\infty, 0)$. By appropriate inversion theorems for the generalised Cauchy–Stieltjes transform, one should be able to figure out that $F$ is zero almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't think I understand well either of these proofs. Could you add some more details?

Comment: In particular, I have these questions (1) can one show that $u(0,s) = 0$ implies $u = 0$ in a whole neighborood of $\{ x = 0\}$ by using the mean value property instead of the maximum principle? (2) Do you have a reference for the unique continuation principle? (3) Is there a version of the unique cont. princ. that allows to deduce the result alrady from $u(0,s) = 0$? (4) What do you mean by "Mellin convolution"? (5) Why is the Mellin transform of that kernel everywhere non zero and why does this imply that the Mellin transform of $F$ is zero?

Comment: Tried to add some details. (1) I modified the argument to one that avoids the maximum principle, but uses power series expansion rather than the mean value property. (But, honestly, I fail to see a reason why one might want to avoid the maximum principle.) (2) This follows immediately from the fact that harmonic functions are real-analytic. (3) Not sure what you are asking for here. (4) The integral $\int_0^\infty f(s) g(x/s) ds/s$  (5) I added a short argument why the Mellin transform is non-zero; then one uses the fact that the transform of the Mellin convolution is the product of transforms

Comment: Thank you! Could you also add the details of the second argument related to point (2), that is, the one using maximum principle and unique continuation?

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand what you are asking for in your last comment.

Comment: I was asking if you could add the details also for your original argument, i.e. that $u$ is identically zero using maximum principle and unique continuation principle (instead of power series expansion)

Comment: Oh, now I see. I did not think about the details, and I realise I may have been too optimistic. What I meant is that, unless $u$ is constant, if in every ball around $(0,s)$ the function $u$ necessarily takes both a positive and a negative value (for otherwise $(0,s)$ would be a local extremum). This is not possible if $u(x,s)$ is radial with respect to $x$, but now I fail to see a simple proof of that fact which would avoid using the fact that $u$ is real-analytic.

Comment: I see, thanks! If a simple proof of that comes to your mind, please let me know